# string "c" is the latest item, why it is not break?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I think this code should be break. positon of "c" in string "abc" is -1, so it should break, but why didn't?

```
string = "abc"
print(string[-1])
while True:
    position = string.find("c")
    if position == -1:
        break
    string = string[:position] + "f" + string[position+len("c"):]
print(string)
```

I think this code should be break. positon of "c" in string "abc" is -1, so it should break, but why didn't?

Comment: string = "cabc"
print(string[-1])
while True:
    position = string.find("c")
    if position == -1:
        break
    string = string[:position] + "f" + string[position+len("c"):]
print(string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indexing syntax `mystr[-1]` gives you the last element of `mystr`, but that is a convenience of the indexing syntax. When you use `find()` you get a number counting from zero, so 2 in this case. The return value `-1` means *not found*.

You are overgeneralizing the `-1` convention: it doesn't apply to `find`. If it did, then  `string.find("c")` could equally well return -1 or 2 in this example because both would be correct. That would be inconvenient, to say the least.

Comment: The `-1` is not a "convention" that gives the last element, it just is a python tool that means : If I request a negative index, begin from the end of string instead of the beginning.

Comment: When you decide that negative indexes count from the end of the string, that *is* a convention. Without that convention, negative indexes would always be out of range, as they are in many other languages. It is a different way of interpreting what negative numbers mean.

Comment: I think I can agree with you on this point. Where I disagree though is that your answer could make him think that the -1 index is just a way to request to last item, when there is a whole more complicated system behind. But that may be just me that is complicating things

Answer (score 1):

`str.find` gives a positive integer index, so `position = 2` in your example.

The preferred solution is to simply test against the length of your string:

```
if position == len(string) - 1:
    # do something
```

Alternatively, for the negative index, you can redefine `position`:

```
position = string.find('c') - len(string)  # -1
```

However, be careful: if your character is not found, `str.find` returns `-1`. So there is good reason why positive integers are preferred in the first place.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509297/9209546) for a diagram of how negative indexing works.

Comment: You may explain how negative indexes works, since it was his original question I believe.  "positon of "c" in string "abc" is -1", he said.

Comment: @IMCoins, Yup I've added a link for that with a useful diagram :)